# Count items with state true in Angular Repeater

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an Angular Repeater which shows the results from my JSON array below. Now only today's items carry the value: 'vandaag = true'.

```
16: {id: "55", datum: "2015-08-17", punt: "dsfga", tellen: 2,…}
datum: "2015-08-17"
id: "55"
punt: "dsfga"
tellen: 2
vandaag: false
17: {id: "63", datum: "2015-08-18", punt: "lkjsdfg", tellen: 1,…}
datum: "2015-08-18"
id: "63"
punt: "lkjsdfg"
tellen: 1
vandaag: true
```

In my Repeater I gave the items of today the class .vandaag:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in results | filter:dateFilter" class="relatief" ng-class="{vandaag: r.vandaag === true}">
```

CSS understands this the right way, but JQuery doesn't. I'm used to count items by class, but the don't seem to exist when i check the class. Because now it returns 0:

```
$http.post('../ajax_crud.php', {positief: 'get', userId: userId, datumText: datumText}).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.results = data;

                        var vandaag = $('.vandaag').length;
                        console.log(vandaag);
                    });
```

So my question is: How to count the items with class .vandaag the right way?

Comment: try `$rootScope.$digest()` before counting class occurance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just count the filtered results, like so:

```
<!--Assign the filtered list to a new var called "filtered"-->
<div ng-repeat="r in filtered = (results | filter:dateFilter)" class="relatief" ng-class="{vandaag: r.vandaag === true}">

//Access new "filtered" var
var vandaag = $scope.filtered.filter(function(r) {
    return r.vandaag === true;
}).length;
```

Comment: Ok, that's almost there... Only some of my filtered results have the value 'vandaag'. So I want to count only these items within my filtered results